# On explaining weird applications of something in a scientific/technical context

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, meaning-in-context, idiom-requests, scientific-language

I'm going to write a paper on weird and unusual applications of tool A. Is there any appropriate term/single word or idiomatic phrase to point to such odd applications in the scientific context? 
Specifically, the option is needed for the title:

> On ------ applications of "A".

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to do this in formal language for papers is

**[novel](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/novel)**

> Interestingly new or unusual. ‘Four landers will explore for subsurface liquid water using a **novel** low-frequency sounding method.’

Comment: +1 for the answer but the suggested term could not reflect the idea.

Comment: @Eilia - Oh boy, I'm afraid I do not understand your comment.

Comment: :) I mean "novel" is a good option but not a convincing one for what I want to express. As in your example sentence, "...using a novel low-frequency sounding method.". In my case, the application is not intrinsically a new one, it's an unusual one by using "Tool/method A". So, the "Tool/method A" is leveraged for another purpose rather than what it is initially intended for.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the word **unconventional**. According to [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/unconventional) it means:

> Not adhering to convention; out of the ordinary.
>
> Not conforming to accepted rules or standards,

Consequently, your title would become:

> On [unconventional applications](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unconventional+applications+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunconventional%20applications%3B%2Cc0) of "A".

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the exact opposite of 'typical':

[**atypical**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/atypical)

> not typical : irregular, unusual

Alternative:

[**peculiar**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/peculiar)

> 1. Different to what is normal or expected; strange.
> 2. Particular; special.

Answer (score 1):

A word which has the sense of *weird and unusual* is ***unlikely***.

> On ***Unlikely*** Applications of "A".

Similar examples:

> [Web search for "unlikely applications
>   of"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unlikely+applications+of%22)

Macmillan:

> **[unlikely](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/unlikely#unlikely_12)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>   **2** not typical
>   He’s a very unlikely romantic hero.
>   **Synonyms and related words:**   Unusual in an interesting way: unusual, special,
>   unique...
>
> **a.** used about two people or things that do not combine well together
>   His parents seem an unlikely couple.

Answer (score 1):

If the scientific domain is medicine-adjacent, your audience would understand [**off label**](https://www.fda.gov/forpatients/other/offlabel/default.htm) for using a medication or treatment for something other than it's explicit regulator-approved use.

Answer (score -1):

**bizarre** is a 'cousin to weird!  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bizarre)

> very strange or unusual, especially in a striking or shocking way. See
>   Synonyms at fantastic.

As in:

> On the **bizarre** applications of "A".